# How to organise bigger multi-class GUI projects?

Tags: c++, class, project

I have made a console application which does something. It looks like:

```
class C
    {
    public:
        void print()
        {
            print("something that only class C knows");
        }
    }   
//**************************************    

class B
    {
    public:
        void print()
        {
            print("something that only class B knows");

            for_each(C c)
            {
                c.print();
            }
        }

    private:
        std::vector<C> c_classes;
    }
//**************************************

class A
    {
    public:
        void print()
        {   
            print("something that only class A knows");

            for_each(B b)
            {
                b.print();
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<B> b_classes;
    }
```

And works nice in console, where I can print from everywhere.

The problem appears when I want to port this application to GUI. I need to show everything that classes A, B and C knows. What is the best way to do this?

I thought to make class A return reference to vector of classes B (which returns reference to vector of classes C) and get values from each instance in GUI class.

But I don't want to make GUI class so much dependent from these classes.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: To me, it seems that this is not strictly about console/GUI, but about what you want to do with the output.  In your console application, you just dump the output to the screen, you can do this in a GUI too, but you probably want a better presentation in your GUI.  I guess there are a couple of ways to do this based on what you really need and what you plan to accept as compromise.

Comment: I want to show values from classes in table. Each class provides a number of columns of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a common interface `Printable` that has a pure virtual `print()` method (possibly returning a string), and have a vector of pointers to this objects somewhere. Have classes `A`, `B` and `C` derive from `Printable`. So when you want to print the stats of each object, just iterate through this vector and display the output.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to get data out of a class hierarchy is using the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  This way, the hierarchy is traversed (similar to what you have now) and a result is made that can be used by the GUI.  This result could be an std::map with object-name as key and printed string as value; this map can be used by the GUI to make its table.

The downside is that a visitor initially creates some extra complexity that hopefully pays off later.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers is to implement a "to_string()" member, which exists in every class and returns a string with relevant data (for example, this is the way it is done in all Java programs).

Alternatively, you could overload the ostream << operator for your specific class. There should be plenty of examples on the net describing how to do this.

Comment: You need a common base class (interface) in order to store the objects in one container, and you need a virtual method no matter that you call it `print()`, `visit()` or `to_string()`.